# Comprehension with Lists of Dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I know this isn't exactly the first question about list comprehensions, but I've been looking around and experimenting for a while and can't figure this one out. I'll apologize in advance, I'm a self-taught novice learning from failures.

This is working code, but it screams list comprehension. I understand list comprehensions and use them, but the combination of stacking ***for*** and working with the dictionaries within the lists is breaking my brain. How would you simplify this:

```
results = []
for system in systems:  # list of dicts
    for result in telnet_results:   # list of dicts
        if system['master_ip'] == result['master_ip']:
            combined = {**system, **result}  # merge dicts, right takes precedence
            results.append(combined)
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
results = [{**system, **result} for system in systems for result in telnet_results if 
           system['master_ip'] == result['master_ip']]
```

Can be also splitted more logically:

```
results = [{**system, **result}
           for system in systems
           for result in telnet_results
           if system['master_ip'] == result['master_ip']]
```

Is this "simplified"? I'm not sure. List comprehensions are not magic, and they do not always simplify the code or make it more readable.